# when I am making a list out of a row in a dataframe, It is iterating only once in the for loop and when do the same with a column it works fine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate through a row in dataframe and on every iteration I want to change some values in the dictionary. I did the same with a column and the output was fine but when i use a row it only iterates once. what should I do.

here is a part of my code-

```
  for c in df[count:count+1,4:16]:
        if(c < 40):
            no_of_failed_assessment = no_of_failed_assessment +1
```

this is a loop inside another loop ie an inner loop. count is being incremented on every iteration of the outer loop.

Now this row has 15 values. but it is only iterating once. and at once all the values in it are showing.

I have done same thing with a column and it iterated as a list should.

what should I do iterate it, like a column?

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Most likely, loops are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over values in the DataFrame with the `.values` attribute. Also, to ensure consistency in integer position-based indexing, I would recommend you use `iloc` (from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)):

```
for c in df.iloc[count,4:16].values: # the count+1 upper bound is not necessary
    if(c < 40):
       no_of_failed_assessment = no_of_failed_assessment +1
```